# How do I connect with ASP.NET Core SignalR endpoint with Silverlight 5?

Tags: silverlight-5.0, asp.net-core-signalr

Is there any workaround to establish a connection between silverlight 5(out of browser) app & ASP.Net Core Signalr host?

I can see Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client package is not compatible with Silverlight. :(

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're out of luck here. That said, if this Silverlight app is something you still need to support going forward, you need to get it off Silverlight. Unfortunately, Microsoft pushed Silverlight hard and then the entire technology flopped, causing devs to end up with apps that are essentially dead. WPF is still supported, works with .NET Core 3.0, and *should* be a fairly seamless transition from Silverlight, but you're going to need to move somehow to something else.

Comment: 1. Download the client source code from https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR/tree/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client & target the same to silverlight. Create a package & push it to local nuget repo. Refer the same on silverlight project.

2. Use the silverlight webbrowser control & load up a page which interacts(using js client) with signalr host. From silverlight, interact with webbrowser control. Hope we can register callbacks.

What do you think about these approaches? Thank You.

Comment: ASP.NET SignalR is not the same thing as ASP.NET Core SignalR.

Comment: Agree that, but this is AspNetCore(https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR/tree/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client) implementation by Microsoft. Am trying to target the same to silverlight. Keep you posted on this. :)

Comment: Oh. Yeah, that's the archived version. Everything was move to aspnet/AspNetCore long ago, so I was thinking it was not Core. So: 1) Watch which repos you're using. Most of those are there only as an archive for older code, and not maintained any longer. 2) It likely can't be targeted to Silverlight anwyays. You'd have to target it to .NET Standard, and I'm not sure Silverlight supports any version of .NET Standard.